# How to prompt the user to enter a integer within a certain amount of numbers

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I was trying to figure out what statement to use to get the user to enter a number between 1 and 10.

here is what i have so far.

```
int a;
printf("Enter a number between 1 and 10: \n);
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Comment: You've inadvertently answered your own question with your tag - use a "while-loop".

Comment: And the problem of this is...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int input;

while (true){
    scanf("%d",&input);
    if (input>=1 && input<=10){
        // process with your input then use break to end the while loop
    }
    else{
        printf("Wrong input! try Again.");
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty poor design. It would be better to loop while the input is invalid and then handle the processing after that. Also means that you can get rid of the artificial loop condition and loop on `input` instead. As a side note, the presence of `continue` in C code is almost always a certain indication of poor design.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `do .. while` loop?

```
int a;

do {
  printf("Enter a number between 1 and 10: \n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
} while (a < 1 || a > 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Number beteween 1 to 10 right? so first stage you must validate if input is integer or not then you will check for range,

Below code is what i mention

```
#define MAX_RANGE 10
int input;
if (scanf("%d",&input) != 1) 
{
    printf ("Really bad input please enter integer number like in range 1 - 10\n");

}
```

Now in second stage as follows

```
if (input < 1 || input > MAX_RANGE) {
   printf("It's an integer but out of range error\n");
}
```

You can also use `while..loop` for same as follows

```
int input;

while (scanf("%d", &input) == 1 && input > 1 && input < 10)

{

    // process your input

}
```