# How do you get C to produce output from number inputted in code?

Tags: c

What code do you have to include to get C to produce an output from number inputted into the system.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int z;
    printf("Please enter a number");
    return 0;
}
```

I want the programme to work out a mathematical equation to the number that the user enters, for example if I enter 5 I want it to work out the exponent 2 of 1 up  to that integer input.

Comment: Here is a small discussion about [entering a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770397/how-to-prompt-the-user-to-enter-a-integer-within-a-certain-amount-of-numbers). This must be done before you consider any computation and output.

Comment: The code you have posted has little relevance to the problem you describe. Have tried anything to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scanf function to get input from user like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int z;
   printf("Please enter a number");
   scanf("%d", &z);

   // do your calculations on z

   printf("Result: %d", z);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the scanf function.

For a number (or in your case an integer specifically) the line is

```
scanf("%d", &z);
```

where the %d specifies that its reading in an integer and the &z is a pointer to your integer variable z.

Information here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

I'm guessing you're new to C programming, so once you get the basics down I would suggest familiarizing yourself with pointers as they are a critical aspect of the language. Some useful resource here using google-fu : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm